# Is there a method to convert a letter into it's index in a tuple in python?

Tags: python, indexing, tuples

What I mean by the question is if I had:
`alphabet:["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]`
and received an input of "a" I would get back an index of 1, or z to get back an index of 26, from the tuple's index. I'm wondering if there is an easier way instead of using a dictionary.
So like if I receive an input of an item from the alphabet tuple, it will return the index.
I am asking this because I am creating a simple caesar cipher encode/decoder and I just want to add 3 to the index which will then be used to create another variable that has the whole alphabet shifted by an index of 3 so "a" becomes "d" and "z" becomes "c".

Comment: Note that if you do not care about the ``alphabet`` tuple, and actually just want to go from letter to number and back again, there's ``ord`` and ``chr``.

Answer (score 1):

same trick as with C, assuming english alphabet:

```
idx = ord(x) - ord('a') + 1
```

(The plus one because you requested '1' for the value 'a')

Answer (score 0):

`string.ascii_lowercase` already has all letters in order (as a string), so you could define a function like:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def letter_position(letter: str) -> int:
    if len(letter) > 1:
        return 0
    return ascii_lowercase.find(letter.lower()) + 1
```

This function works both with uppercase and lowercase letters, and returns `0` if something other than a single alphabet letter is passed onto it (so `'a'` returns `1`, `'B'` returns `2`, but `'ab'` and `'!'` both return `0`):

```
>>> letter_position('a')
1
>>> letter_position('B')
2
>>> letter_position('ab')
0
>>> letter_position('!')
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is the right way to go here.  You should handle any "offsets" with a function outside of the dictionary.

```
# secret coder
alphabet = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ')

# make dictionaries for encode / decode
key = {ltr:idx for idx, ltr in enumerate(alphabet)}
reverse_key = {idx:ltr for idx, ltr in enumerate(alphabet)}

# do the "tricky stuff" with a function

def encode(word, offset):
    result = []
    for letter in word:
        result.append(key[letter] + offset)
    return result

def decode(code, offset):
    result = []
    for num in code:
        result.append(reverse_key[num - offset])
    return ''.join(result)

# take it for a test drive...

secret_key = 5  # select anything you want, just use same for encode/decode

secret = encode('dog food', secret_key)
print(secret)

# get back the original w/ the secret key
retrieved = decode(secret, secret_key)
print(retrieved)
```

#### Output:

```
[8, 19, 11, 31, 10, 19, 19, 8]
dog food
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your caeser cipher:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase


def encode(s, offset):
    offset %= 26
    result = []
    for ch in s:
        substitute = ascii_lowercase.index(ch) + offset
        result.append(ascii_lowercase[substitute % 26])
    return ''.join(result)


def decode(s, offset):
    offset %= 26
    result = []
    for ch in s:
        original = ascii_lowercase.index(ch) - offset
        result.append(ascii_lowercase[original])
    return ''.join(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = 'abcdefwxyza'
    for i in range(-100, 100):
        assert(decode(encode(s, i), i) == s)
```

Answer (score 0):

To encode/decode a string, [translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) / [make_trans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) could be used to create a cipher.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as lc, ascii_uppercase as uc


def encode(s, offset):
    return s.translate(
        str.maketrans(lc+uc,
                      lc[offset:]+lc[:offset]+uc[offset:]+uc[:offset]))

def decode(s, offset):
    return s.translate(
        str.maketrans(lc+uc,
                      lc[26-offset:]+lc[:26-offset]+uc[26-offset:]+uc[:26-offset]))

s = 'Hello World!'

encoded = encode(s, 3)
print(encoded)
decoded = decode(encoded, 3)
print(decoded)
```

Prints

```
Khoor Zruog!
Hello World!
```